counting occurrences of unique tuples with AggregateFunction in ClickHouse
I'm working with game session data in ClickHouse and trying to implemented a count of unique occurrences inside an AggregateFunction.
These are the details of the scenario:

A materialized view summarizes each "play session", from the moment a player enters the game until they leave.

Games are made up of many different "worlds", or "mini games", that may be visited in a single "play session".

Each world or mini-game has multiple levels.


Every time a player moves between worlds or levels, an event is captured that includes, among other fields, the following:
SELECT
toUUID(simpleJSONExtractString(gamePayload, 'play_id')) as play_id,
simpleJSONExtractString(gamePayload, 'game_id') as game_id,
simpleJSONExtractString(gamePayload, 'level_id') as level_id,

My goal is, while rolling data up by play_id, to calculate a summary of unique combinations of game_id and level_id, and how many times they were visited in a single play_session.
I am currently extracting unique tuples with:
SCHEMA
`games_levels` SimpleAggregateFunction(groupUniqArrayArray, Array(Tuple(String, String))),


SELECT
groupUniqArrayArraySimpleState([tuple(game_id, level_id)]) AS games_levels,

But this does not provide a count of unique tuple occurrences.
Any help would be appreciated!

Is there any reason you cant simply convert this to a string and and use AggregateFunction(uniq)?

I'm assuming the order of play_id,  game_id and level_id matter.
I personally would just use a uniqExactState(play_id || game_id || level_id) in the view, but if you must use a tuple maybe just use groupUniqArrayState and take the length when merging.
CREATE TABLE test
(
    `s` Tuple(play_id String, game_id String, level_id String)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY tuple()

-- some random data

INSERT INTO test SELECT (concat('p', floor(randUniform(1, 1000, 1))), concat('g', floor(randUniform(1, 100, 2))), concat('l', floor(randUniform(1, 10, 3))))
FROM numbers(10000)

-- test expected answer

SELECT uniqExact(concat(s.1, s.2, s.3))
FROM test

9947


-- using states and merging - i skip the MV but should give you the idea

SELECT length(groupUniqArrayMerge(state))
FROM
(
    SELECT groupUniqArrayState(s) AS state
    FROM test
)


-- with mv 

CREATE TABLE uTest
(
    `s` AggregateFunction(groupUniqArray, Tuple(play_id String, game_id String, level_id String))
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY tuple()


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW testMV TO uTest
AS SELECT groupUniqArrayState(s) AS s
FROM test

TRUNCATE test

INSERT INTO test SELECT (concat('p', floor(randUniform(1, 1000, 1))), concat('g', floor(randUniform(1, 100, 2))), concat('l', floor(randUniform(1, 10, 3))))
FROM numbers(10000)

SELECT uniqExact(concat(s.1, s.2, s.3))
FROM test
-- 9938

SELECT length(groupUniqArrayMerge(s))
FROM uTest
-- 9938

-- just to be sure

INSERT INTO test SELECT (concat('p', floor(randUniform(1, 1000, 1))), concat('g', floor(randUniform(1, 100, 2))), concat('l', floor(randUniform(1, 10, 3))))
FROM numbers(100000000)

SELECT uniqExact(concat(s.1, s.2, s.3))
FROM test

-- 890109

SELECT length(groupUniqArrayMerge(s))
FROM uTest

-- 890109

1 row in set. Elapsed: 0.914 sec.

